# UWP toast custom sound doesn't play

Tags: c#, notifications, uwp, toast, universal

I have this toast to show up and everything is fine except audio. I was trying to put toast.mp3 in different locations like projects main folder, Assets etc. and even used path like D:/MyProjectPath/Assets/toast.mp3 and still notification is silent. I am a beginner so maybe I miss something... And of course I've looked for solution but nothing has been helpful.Here is my code:

```
string xml = $@"<toast scenario=""reminder"">
        <visual>
        <binding template=""ToastGeneric"">
            <text>{name}</text>
            <text>{quantity} {unit}</text>
            <text>{beforeorafter}</text>

        </binding>
        </visual>
        <actions>
        <input id=""snoozeTime"" type=""selection"" defaultInput=""10"">
            <selection id=""5"" content=""5 minutes""/>
            <selection id=""10"" content=""10 minutes""/>
            <selection id=""15"" content=""15 minutes""/>
        </input>
        <action activationType=""system"" arguments=""snooze"" hint-inputId=""snoozeTime"" content=""""/>
        <action activationType=""system"" arguments=""dismiss"" content=""""/>
        </actions>
        <audio src = ""ms-appx:///Assets/toast.mp3"" loop = ""true""></audio>
        </toast>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below Tutorial on MSDN. I tried this with a sample and it worked exactly as intended.

[Quickstart: Sending a Toast notification with custom audio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2016/06/18/quickstart-sending-a-toast-notification-with-custom-audio/)

Also see below

> **Known Issue:** If you’re using Desktop Version 1511, the custom toast
>   audio will only work if your app is installed via the Store. That
>   means you cannot locally test your custom audio on Desktop before
>   submitting to the Store – but the audio will work fine once installed
>   from the Store. We fixed this in the Anniversary Update, so that
>   custom audio from your locally deployed app will work correctly.

So that might be your problem. This is fixed in Anniversary update.

Comment: Just updated to version 1607 (14393.51) and still toast is using default sound.

Comment: It was silent before now it plays default sound. Si that's a good start. Now in the example above you can see that audio is added in backend. Try that and see if your audio plays.